# Better understanding of the SimpleAdapter's ViewBinder

Tags: android, simpleadapter, android-viewbinder

I have 4 `TextViews`, 2 `ImageViews`, 2 `Buttons` and 2 widgets that are part of a row definition in a `ListView`. The data comes from XML and a `SimpleAdapter`. To access these `TextViews` I implement the `ViewBinde`r in a custom class and override the `setViewValue`. This works and the two `TextViews` I want to dynamically change are handled in the `setViewValue`. What is confusing to me is why my other two TextViews don't get passed through `setViewValue`. I say this based upon setting a breakpoint where the execution thread only enters twice. I was expecting to see it 4 or more times?

Here is the `setViewValue` where I have a breakpoint set.

```
@Override     
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String text)
{
    if(view.getId() == R.id.txtvw1)
    {             
//blah do some stuff
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.txtvw2)
    {
//Blah do some stuff
    }

    return true;
}
```

xml declaration of the `TextViews`(1 shows and 4 doesn't):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="@string/str_StaticA"
        android:textColor="#C0F700" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="IMHO:"
        android:textColor="#FFBA19" />
```

So in summary why does the execution enter the override only twice AND it just so happens to be the exact two I want to update?

Well through additional reading and deductive reasoning a few more pieces of information have come to light. In my mind ever View in the `ListView` row XML would pass through the `ViewBinder` but that was WRONG! From what I can figure you attach the `ViewBinder` to the DataAdapter via `setViewBinder`. Well since the DataAdapter is told what View(s) to use to populate the data in it it makes sense that only the two were showing. I was only revealing two to it.

Here is a snippet where I specify the Views involved in the populating process and pass them on the constructor of the DataAdapter:

```
String[] from = new String[] {"txtvw_PrevLift", "txtvw_PrevReps", "ActuLiftPikr", "ActulRepsPikr" };
int[] to = {R.id.txtvw_PrevLift, R.id.txtvw_PrevReps, R.id.ActuLiftPikr, R.id.ActulRepsPikr };

LiftDataAdapter LiftDataAdapter = new LiftDataAdapter(this, LiftDataMaps, R.layout.liftdatalayout, from, to);
```

While this seems to make sense I don't know that my deductive reasoning is accurate. Will update as I find more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set a `ViewBinder` on `SimpleAdapter` **all** the `Views` you declared(in the `to` array in your case) will be passed to the `ViewBinder`'s `setViewValue()` method no matter what. If the `setViewValue` method doesn't return `true` meaning the data binding for that `View` has failed(for whatever reason) then you get the default action(for a `TextView`), setting the text from the data `Hashmap`. Right now you declared the `setViewValue` to do something for only two `TextViews`(checking by their ids) and also to return `true` **no matter what**. When you'll enter the `setViewValue` for the other `Views` in your row layout you'll again enter the `setViewValue`, don't match the ids(so no updates for those `Views`) and return `true`(which will tell the adapter that the binding was **successful** and this `View` doesn't require any more work). [A look at the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#SimpleAdapter.bindView%28int,android.view.View%29) for the `SimpleAdapter.bindView` method will show you how the `ViewBinder` is used.

Also, I see that you use a custom adapter, are you sure you don't interfere with the normal `SimpleAdapter` logic?(also don't use the same name for the class and variable name)

Comment: Roger on naming the class and variable the same. You are correct and I was just typing fast for the posting. As for returning true I understand what you are sayng by ALWAYS returning true from setViewValue. I am looking at the link provided now to find a better way to return from setViewValue so it is accurate not just hardcoded.

Comment: Dude that is awesome. I didn't know you could get a look into source code like that. Double Thank You.